# Trim email address in checkout

Tags: checkout

I have been doing some user testing and noticed that lots of people put in a space after their email address i.e. "name@domain.com "

[image: Error message]

Magento shows a red box error on it, but some users get confused and don't know what to do. Is there a easy way of trimming the space from the email, through either code or javascript?

Answer (score 6):

Add the below script in any of your `js` file.

```
Validation.add('validate-email', 'Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.', function(v) {
    var emailInput = v.trim();
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(emailInput) || /^([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*@([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*\.(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){2,})$/i.test(emailInput);
})
```

**Note :** Above code will not work on `RWD` theme, because they have used `html5` attribute `type="email"` to the input field.

Answer (score 2):

first check what JS your checkout is using. 
u can use the google cmd+alt+I (i am using mac)

then see what JS are beeing used.

the past

```
Validation.add('validate-email', 'Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.', function(v) {
    var emailInput = v.trim();
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(emailInput) || /^([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*@([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*\.(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){2,})$/i.test(emailInput);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all blank spaces before magento form validation

```
$(':input').change(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
});
```